# Hive query to get the count based on the conditions

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have following data in my hive table

[image]

Expecting following output

[image]

if we look at ID 1, it has CD1 as met and not met, so I need to take Met row and for that date(10/10/2020), I need to show count1. similarly for ID 2, we have 2 rows with notmet and decline as CD1 values. for this combination I need to take notmet row and for that date I need to show notmet count as 1.

Could you please help how we can implement this. I tried with case statement but it is not working.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks...

Comment: Isn't it just a select statement?  ```select date, count(1) from cd_table where id=1 and CD1=met and date='10/10/2020' = 0
```

Comment: We don't know which date it has met. We need to find met and then for that row we need to take date and show as count 1. if I use simple date and count, I will get count by each date which I don't want - I mean I don't want to have 10/12 in the report.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this - where i flagged the row when its met or not met and then sum it up.

```
select 
date,
SUM( case when lower(CD1) = 'met' then 1 else 0 end ) as Met_count,
SUM( case when lower(CD1) = 'notmet' then 1 else 0 end ) as NotMet_count
from table
WHERE date in (select date from table where  lower(CD1) = 'met')
group by date
```

Comment: Thank you Roy for the response. for 2 different dates, I have MET and NOTMET on CD1. for this I need to take only one date which is "MET" and need to sum up as 1. In the query you provided, will give me MET count 1 for 1day and NOTMET count 1 for other day. We should not consider NOTMET at all in our sum.

Comment: i see, i will change sql now.